# Why did Spider-man have a six legged spider emblem on his costume?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, costume

I saw a funny panel Slytherincess posted in chat. It has a six legged emblem on Spideys costume. Is this a Stan Lee sanctioned version of the webslinger? [image: Spider-man]

Is there a back story?

Comment: He was originally known as cricketman, and couldn't afford a new costume after the brand change. You have any idea what a tailor costs in 1960s NYC? He's already living in a studio apartment in the crack district as it is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's from the 1967 Spider-Man cartoon series, which included Stan Lee as a "Creative Consultant".  The [1967 cartoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_%281967_TV_series%29) series has given rise to an [internet meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/spider-man) involving taking screenshots from the series and adding "witty" text to it.

So while it is a product approved by Stan Lee, like most cartoons, complex designs must be simplified.  It's the same reason that most cartoon people have 3 or 4 fingers and not 5 like a real person would have.  Thus, an 8 legged spider now has 6 legs, making it look like a tick instead.

Comment: The shape does look like a tick, but [ticks are arachnids, and have 8 legs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick). ;)

Comment: Curse you and your knowledge!!!  :)  They, uh, pulled two legs off the tick...  And beat it up...  And threw it into the garbage... Yeah... that's it.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this answer. How on Earth is a 6-legged spider a "simpler" design than an 8-legged one? Is there any reference explaining this is why Spiderman's emblem looked the way it did? If drawing complexity was the issue, it would make more sense to remove Spidey's webbing on his mask, which is more complex to draw than an additional 2 legs in his emblem!

Comment: Notice that while there is webbing on his head, there is none on the red areas on his arms.

Comment: @AndresF. “How on Earth is a 6-legged spider a "simpler" design than an 8-legged one?” When you’re drawing the damn thing 24 times per second, it’s simpler.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I understand that, but 2 additional legs are insignificant compared to the webbing on his mask, for example. When drawing 24 fps, it's simpler to remove the webbing thant a couple of legs!

Comment: @AndresF. sure, but take away the webbing on his mask and he's not Spider-Man any more. Take away two legs from the spider on his back, and no-one notices until it's 30 years later and we all have nothing better to do than look at this stuff on the internet all day.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hah hah, point taken! :D

Comment: And 30, no _40_, OMG! _**50**_ years ago, nobody could record it on _any_ sort of medium to nit pick over it - it just went by in a flash and you may have though, "was that only 6 legs? Naaaah... couldn't have been..."